# Sql Server 2008 - Cannot connect to local default instance

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I recently rebuilt my machine to Windows 7 x64, installed Sql Server 2008 enterprise.  I can connect fine to other remote instances via Management Studio (be they 2000, 2005 or 2008), but i cannot find my local default instance.

- I have verified that a directory was created for the default instance C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER
- I can connect to SQLEXPRESS instance fine
- I have rerun setup to ensure I have everything installed
- I have verified that the SQLSERVER(MSSQLSERVER) service is running
- I have verified that SQL Server Browser is running
- I have tried brownsing for the instance and see all the others available except my local one
- I have tried using this for servername: TSOUTHERLANDPC\MSSQLSERVER, the first part being my local machine name

My issue is not the same as [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/19084/cant-connect-to-local-database-in-sql-server-2008-management-studio) or [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/11745/i-cannot-connect-to-my-local-sql-server-2008).

Any ideas?

Comment: cant figure out how to post another answer even tho I have enough reputation... but would like to offer my resolution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

re-install sql server. I had the same problem and then noticed that instead of installing a local instance I installed a named instance ( that just so happened to be the same name as a local instance).  For some reason there is a difference between a local instance with the exact same name as a local instance and when you actually choose local instance.

Comment: seriously? ugg..  There is no way to setup a default instance if you chose named instance during install?  And I very well could have done as it's been a few weeks since I installed.

Comment: You can do another install, if there is no default instance already installed, you will have an option to add a default instance. Once you get things straightened out, just disable the service for the named instance.

Comment: i uninstalled just sql server, and reinstalled selecting the default instance but still get same thing, guess my next step is to uninstall every last bit of it.  I am running Win7 x64 and installed SQL server x64.

Comment: i uninstalled completely and reinstalled but the Developer edition this time (still R2).  I think I chose enterprise the first time around b/c I didn't feel like downloading the developer edition from msdn.  works fine now.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try your hostname followed by the instancename, for instance PC\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Right I've tried that.  SQLEXPRESS works fine, but MSSQLSERVER, which is the default instance, does not.

Comment: I tried MYMACHINE\LOCAL and got in finally.  Running developer version of 2008 R2.
Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Check the configuration manager and make sure the browser is running.

Comment: SQL Server Browser is running.

Answer (score 1):

The instance name that you should use for the default instance is the hostname of your machine, so try just `tsoutherlandpc` and see if that does it for you.

Comment: I get login failed when I try that. I'm using windows auth.

Comment: after a complete reinstall, and using the developer edition this time, this approach works.

Answer (score 1):

As stupid as this sounds, open SQL Management Studio by using Right Click -> Run As Administrator.

You should now be able to connect to your default instance.

This is a wonderfully undocumented 'feature' that occurs on any of the newer Windows OS' with UAC enabled.

Comment: +1 - This worked for me.